# Translating a dictionary of paramters into a list of keys

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, multidimensional-array

I've found some inconsistent behavior when iterating through a list of lists, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand what is going on.

I have a dictionary of parameters: `params = {'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'numbers': ['1', '2']}`, and I would like to translate these into a list of keys, where a key is a permutation of the parameters, so the keys would be `[['a', '1'], ['a', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '1'], ['c', '2'], ['d', '1'], ['d', '2']]`.

EDIT: This becomes tricky when `params` is extensible. `params` might contain just `letters`, or it might contain `letters`, `numbers`, and `names` (or even 10 different things). This is why something like `for letter in params['letters']: for number in params['numbers']: blah` won't work.

My code:

```
    keys = []
    params = {'letters': ['a','b','c','d'], 'numbers': ['1', '2']}

    for param in params:
      if not keys:
        for thing in params[param]:
          keys.append([thing])
        print keys
        continue
      cur_len = len(keys)
      keys *= len(params[param])
      print keys
      print '\n'
      for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
        key.append(params[param][idx/cur_len])
        print keys, '\n'
```

And the output:

```
    [['a', '1'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['a', '1'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]

    [['a', '1'], ['b', '1'], ['c'], ['d'], ['a', '1'], ['b', '1'], ['c'], ['d']]

    ...

    [['a', '1'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '1'], ['d', '1'], ['a', '1'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '1'], ['d', '1']]

    [['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '1'], ['d', '1'], ['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '1'], ['d', '1']]

    ...

    [['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1', '2'], ['c', '1', '2'], ['d', '1', '2'], ['a', '1', '2'], ['b', '1', '2'], ['c', '1', '2'], ['d', '1', '2']]
```

Why are numbers appended to indexes 0 and 4, then 1 and 5, etc.?

ANSWER (credit Martin Evans below):
This works best if `params` is an OrderedDict

```
    from itertools import product
    from collections import OrderedDict

    params = OrderedDict()
    params['letters'] = ['a','b','c','d']
    params['numbers'] = ['1', '2']
    keys = list(product(*params.keys()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Python's [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function which in effect automates nested for loops for you. For example:

```
from itertools import product

params = {'letters': ['a','b','c','d'], 'numbers': ['1', '2']}
keys = list(product(params['letters'], params['numbers']))
print keys
```

Would give you:

```
[('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '1'), ('d', '2')]
```

If a list was used for `params`, you could instead code it as follows:

```
params = [['a','b','c','d'], ['1', '2']]
keys = list(product(*params))
print keys
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for: list(product(*[params[param] for param in params])) to allow for extensible paramters.

Comment: You could try something like `product(*params.keys())`, but as you have a dictionary, the ordering of the parameters is not guaranteed. You might get the numbers first. If you used a list instead, this would be very extensible.

Answer (score 0):

That's way too complex.  Think of it as you're trying to get for each letter, every combination of numbers.  There are several ways to do this:

```
keys = []
params = {'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'numbers': ['1', '2']}
```

Most basic approach:

```
for x in params['letters']:
    for y in params['numbers']:
        keys.append([x, y])
```

Single line:

```
output = [[x,y] for x in params['letters'] for y in params['numbers']]

print(keys)
print(output)
```

Output

```
[['a', '1'], ['a', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '1'], ['c', '2'], ['d', '1'], ['d', '2']]
[['a', '1'], ['a', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '1'], ['c', '2'], ['d', '1'], ['d', '2']]
```

Comment: I left out the extensible-ness of my task. Edited the original question.